# How can I sort into that nulls are last ordered in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I excute this query in the mongo shell

```
db.getCollection('list').find({}).sort({next_time: 1})
```

the result is

```
next_time
--
null
null
null
2015-02-21 00:00:00
2015-03-25 00:00:00
2015-08-29 00:00:00
```

I hope to make the result like this

```
next_time
--
2015-02-21 01:00:00
2015-03-25 01:00:00
2015-08-29 01:00:00
null
null
null
```

The different is that 'null's are last ordered in the list. How can I do for this?

Comment: Have you tried `next_time: -1`?

Comment: Yes, but that is not the result I want. It seems to be confused. I should make up the example.

Comment: Why not do sort({next_time: 1 }) and upon retrieval discard the nulls?  Do you have a lot of nulls?

Comment: The data have many many nulls. Before the starting App 99% of data is null. So I want to find exact solution for that.

Comment: If I execute sort({next_time: 1}), the result is 2015-08-29, 2015-03-25, 2015-02-21, null, null, null but it is not the solution.

Comment: You can see in the upper result, 2015-02-21, 2015-03-25, 2015-08-29, null, null, null. They are similar but not exactly same.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Perhaps you can use aggregation and an artificially high end date:

```
c = db.foo.aggregate([
{$project: {
            next_time: 1,
            nlt: { $ifNull: [ "$next_time", new ISODate("9000-01-01") ] }
  }     
}
,
{$sort: { "nlt": 1}}
                  ]);
c.forEach(function(r) { printjson(r); });
```

Alternatively, if the majority of the material has nulls and you don't want to deal with those docs at all, then filter them out and just `$sort` the remainder:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$match: {"nt": {$exists: true}}}
,
{$sort: { "nt": 1}}
                 ]);
```

Comment: but than, all null values have a wrong `9000-01-01` value assigned which need to be reverted. This feels very wrong and I suppose it is also very slow for huge projections (with small limit). It is very unfortunate MongoDB does not support something like `order by X nulls last`  as in some sql languages. / I believe this is the relevant issue on jira: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24310

Comment: I wonder what the diff in performance is.   The SQL imps still have to choose how to internally optimize sort against an index.   Adding `nulls last` is syntactically easy but it is unclear if that translates to materially better performance.

Comment: Bad performance comes from scanning entire collection and doing sorting at runtime. Having separate field allow you to create pre-sorted index using that field.

Answer (score 6):

If you can add fields to your documents, you could add an "inverted" field that, when you sort it in descending order, would return your documents in ascending order.

Just to clarify: mongo considers null values as the "smallest" ones, so they appear first when sorting in ascending order, and appear last when sorting in descending order.

So, if your elements are like this:

```
{
  ...
  next_time: ISODate("2020-05-01")
}
```

Since `ISODate("2020-05-01").getTime()` is `1588291200000`, you may add:

```
{
  ...
  next_time: ISODate("2020-05-01"),
  next_time_inverted: -1588291200000
}
```

And then sort the inverted value in descending order:

```
db.getCollection('list').find({}).sort({next_time_inverted: -1})
```

Don't forget to add an index on that field when necessary.