# mongodb, sort documents ascending, with undefined bottom

Tags: mongodb, sorting, null

I have documents collection where some documents have price, some don't.
I want to sort them ascending, with null(empty) last.

Googled some solutions:

- Do two queries: first with price not null and price sorting, and second with price is null, and then combine data
- Project new field with aggregate for sorting. Make it equal to price  for documents with price and huge number where price is null. Then sort by this new field.

Is there any better/clean way to do it?

Comment: Any news on this topic? Did you find a better solution?

Comment: @FelipeMicali they have ticket https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24310, I used aggregation framework solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084446/how-can-i-sort-into-that-nulls-are-last-ordered-in-mongodb

Comment: This solution works, but isn't scalable, as the aggregation framework will use a huge amount of memory in large collections. In my situation I need only the first document after sorting, for an internal system requirement, and null results must appear in the results only if there aren't documents with expire dates defined, so I make a recursive/conditional query: first I verify if there is at least one document with expire date: if true, then I keep the null results out of my query with 'expireAt: {$exists: true}'. But this is a restrict solution for my problem. Thanks for your feedback!