# Group objects and then sort these groups using a single query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, kmongo

I need to implement a mongo query that forms 2 group depending if the `avatarUrl` is non null and then sorts these groups by `lastName`.

Here is how the collection looks like:

```
{
    "lastName": "Bradley",
    "avatarUrl": "http://...",
},
{
    "lastName": "Bradley",
    "avatarUrl": null,
},
{
    "lastName": "Chateau",
    "avatarUrl": null,
}
{
    "lastName": "Ezekiel",
    "avatarUrl": "http://...",
},
{
    "lastName": "Zerox",
    "avatarUrl": "http://...",
}
```

And I need this query to return the following list:

```
{
    "lastName": "Bradley",
    "avatarUrl": "http://...",
},
{
    "lastName": "Ezekiel",
    "avatarUrl": "http://...",
},
{
    "lastName": "Zerox",
    "avatarUrl": "http://...",
}
{
    "lastName": "Bradley",
    "avatarUrl": null,
},
{
    "lastName": "Chateau",
    "avatarUrl": null,
}
```

As you can see it is split in two groups and every group is sorted by alphabetical order.

**Is there a way to do so using a single mongo query?**

I tried using this:

```
getCollection().find().sort({ "lastName": 1, "avatarUrl": -1}).toList()
```

But it clearly doesn't work.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084446/how-can-i-sort-into-that-nulls-are-last-ordered-in-mongodb