# How to sort documents in mongodb so that null values appear last

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say my mongo document looks like this:

```
{
  _id: "some _id",
  name: "some name",
  type: "A" | "B" | "C" | or it may be null
}
```

When I call `db.getCollection('mycollection').find().sort({ type: -1 })` I'm getting documents with `type: null` first because *the data is sorted by canonical type where null has much lower canonical value than that of number/string*

Is there a way to form a query, so that null values would appear last?

I have found this question [How can I sort into that nulls are last ordered in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084446/how-can-i-sort-into-that-nulls-are-last-ordered-in-mongodb) but there it's suggested to use aggregation and add "fake" values which does not seem good to me.

Using aggregation may work if forming a facet with sorted documents where sorting criteria is not null and documents where it is null and then concatinating both arrays, but that can get complicated when there're more than one sorting criteria.

Comment: I tried something like your scenario, but the ordering I obtain with `{test: 1}` has not `null` values (with reverse ordering) first and `null`s last, according to your statement that _null has much lower canonical value than that of number/string_. Sorting with `{type: 1}` returns `null`s first and not `null` values last. Which sorting would you like? `null` s last and not `null` values first, but not in reverse ordering?

Comment: @PietroMartinelli I'd like `null` values to be last all the time

Comment: Sorting with `{test: -1}` (I forgot the minus in previous comment) solves the problem, for me - at the price to reverse ordering not `null` values...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operator to get a type of field (`null` or `string`) and then [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) by field type plus then by your field, try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    { $addFields: { fieldType: { $type: "$type" } } },
    { $sort: { fieldType: -1, type: 1 } },
    { $project: { "fieldType": 0 } }
])
```